# Android button disappears after running AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-button

I'm making an app as part of a project which connects to a device on a network (a specific device). After clicking a button, which calls an `AsyncTask`, the button disappears and is not clickable.

I'm using the [`ButtonRectangle`](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/blob/master/MaterialDesign/src/com/gc/materialdesign/views/ButtonRectangle.java) class from this library: https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

The relevant code:

```
// ...

int numAdded = addResultsToDatabase(items);
if(!deviceInitTask.isCancelled() && numAdded > 0) {
    String devices = "device";
    if(numAdded > 1) {
        devices = "devices";
    }
    Toast.makeText(NewLocalDeviceScanResultsActivity.this,
            "Added " + NumberToWords.convert(numAdded) + " " + devices,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // go to device list activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(NewLocalDeviceScanResultsActivity.this, DeviceListActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
else {
    // button disappears
}

// ...
```

The above code is inside an anonymous `OnClickListener` on the `ButtonRectangle` object. The `addResultsToDatabase` method is as follows:

```
// ...

List<String[]> devices = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    ScanResultsRecyclerViewAdapter.ListItem item = items.get(i);
    if(item.isSelected()) {
        String[] device = new String[4];
        device[0] = item.getDescription().trim();
        device[1] = item.getHost().trim();
        device[2] = item.getLoginUsername().trim();
        device[3] = item.getLoginPassword().trim();

        devices.add(device);
    }
}

// try connecting and get results
deviceInitTask = new LocalDeviceInitTask(this, devices);
deviceInitTask.execute();

// ...
```

The `DeviceInitTask` simply tries to connect to the device, log in using the supplied username and password and returns an auth token and expiry if successful. If it cannot connect, `this.cancel(true)` is called from within the task and a Toast is shown.

Note that I'm testing this so that logging in fails, so `numAdded == 0`.

I'm at a loss as to what's causing it. The button still has `View.VISIBLE` after the above code has run. `button.invalidate()` doesn't work.

The only thing that has worked so far is, obviously, recreating the activity, but this isn't ideal because user input is lost and it's just not good practice.

Any advice?

======================

EDIT: so now instead of running a separate `AsyncTask` for each device, all the connecting is done in one task, and the results are handled by `onPostExecute` instead of `task.get()`. The end result is the same - the button vanishes.

======================

UPDATE: I've stepped through the code in debug mode and found that the button disappears after creating a `DefaultHttpClient` object (org.apache.http.impl.client). I'm going to step into that class and see if I can figure out where exactly it happens.

Comment: I think you are not using AsyncTask correctly. You need to get your login details in onPostExecute callback with the AsyncTask

Comment: try implement your own custom AsyncTask instead of calling the result from the get(). Do your background task in doInBackground and depending on the result change the visibility of the button in onPostExecute.

Comment: @hoomi, you're spot on actually....I will try that and see if it works.

Comment: @nahwarang, yes, just finished refactoring now and tested it, and the exact same thing happens. The button just flipping vanishes, despite no actions being called on it at all! (see edit)

Comment: @Kieran can you please post your updated code with the use of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Please check weather you are trying to disable the button within doInBackground() method of your asynctask, if so, you need to out the button disabling code with in the onPostExecute() method. Because UI thread can not be modified from the doInBackground().

Comment: Thanks for the answer, David, however I'm not trying to disable the button at all, which is why this is confusing. The only UI stuff done in the AsyncTask is showing Toasts, which is run on the UI thread.